# Why is the partitive article missing from "on ne gardait pas trace de ces choses-là"?

Tags: articles, négation

Why do we have *pas trace* instead of *pas de trace* as highlighted in this excerpt from L'Étranger by Camus?

> Sur le pas de ma porte, j’ai trouvé le vieux Salamano. Je l’ai fait entrer et il m’a appris que son chien était perdu, car il n’était pas à la fourrière. Les employés lui avaient dit que, peut-être, il avait été écrasé. Il avait demandé s’il n’était pas possible de le savoir dans les commissariats. On lui avait répondu qu’on ne gardait **pas trace** de ces choses-là, parce qu’elles arrivaient tous les jours. J’ai dit au vieux Salamano qu’il pourrait avoir un autre chien, mais il a eu raison de me faire remarquer qu’il était habitué à celui-là.

**Background**

My grammar book says that you have to use the partitive article to mean "not any" and gives these examples:

> Ne buvez pas de vin.
>   Elle n'a pas de plume.

Because *trace* is a countable noun, the Camus sentence would seem to fit the *plume* example.

Please explain the logic behind *pas trace* in a way that I can apply it to other sentences.  For example is it any time the noun in question is itself followed by *de* (as here, *trace de*)?

Comment: Your grammar book is correct. I think “garder trace” (instead of “garder une trace”) is just an idiom, but I can neither think of a more general grammatical construct that it's part of nor find this specific combination of words in a dictionary.

Comment: looks like "on n'a pas idée de dire çà" or "il n'y a pas lieu de discuter", but I just cannot explain the grammatical point that lies here under.

Comment: I agree with @Gilles that “garder (& perdre) trace [de]” (just like “keep/lose track [of]” in English) are probably fixed expressions/idioms.  Also, even if the French noun “trace” is countable/*dénombrable* as you mention (& to the extent that its being countable adds to the confusion), perhaps looking at “keeping/losing track [of]” in English as expressing an uncountable notion as a whole (replacing “maintaining/failing to maintain **awareness** [of]”) might help (where “awareness” is uncountable in English, and perhaps its French counterpart “conscience” is, too).

Answer (score 1):

There are lots and lots of combinations of verb + noun without an article.

- *To have* and common verbs can be combined with a lot of nouns: *avoir envie*, *avoir faim*, *prendre acte*, *prendre froid*, *donner congé*, *donner raison*, …
- It also happens with specific verbs and nouns.

Sometimes the meaning is evident, sometimes, it is specific. It is impossible to know them all. They are in dictionaries.

- *garder trace* = *garder une trace*
- *ne pas garder trace* = *ne pas garder de trace*

Answer (score 0):

Think of

> garder trace de...

as a whole.
"de" would be used in a sentence like:

> on n'en a pas gardé de trace.

Comment: or "on n'en a pas gardé trace"